# Denied permission to write to a folder [Errno 13] Windows 8

Tags: python, windows, permissions

After going into "properties" of the folder I want to write to and changing the permissions to "full control" for all the users, I'm still receiving this error message:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
    File "import-media.py", line 32, in <module> 
        with codecs.open(str(sys.argv[2]), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as g: 
    File "C:'Pythoninstall\lib\codecs.py", line 896, in open
        file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'output'
```

sys.argv[2] is the 'output' directory. 'import-media.py' is meant to create a .csv in 'output' but every time I run it, it says permission has been denied. From what I was reading online it may be a Windows problem, but I haven't gotten further than that on that road of possible solutions. I've also tried the 'attrib -r'command to give permissions to everyone.

Maybe this has something to do with where I've installed python. I'm very new to python, using the command line, and programming generally. I've spent a lot of time reading about other posts but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Please help, any direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: You're trying to open the default data stream of a directory for writing as a regular file, which is not allowed. I think you want something like `path = os.path.join(sys.argv[2], 'output.csv')`, and then open `path` for writing.

Comment: @eryksun thank you! it worked